# Smoothly scroll to anchor tags

Tags: javascript, animation, skrollr

I want to have links in my page that animate the scrolling of the page (actually not the page but the `#scrollable` element, in this case) to the target position.

The following looks very rough, both on mobile and desktop. It seems that [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) could help me with that. How could I implement the following with it?

```
 var scrollable = $('#scrollable'); // whole page container that scrolls, not using native scroll
 var headerDownArrow = $('#header-down-arrow');

  headerDownArrow.on('click', function(){   
    scrollable.animate({
      scrollTop: $("#home-portfolio").offset().top
    }, 1000)
  });
```

I tried this and it doesn't work (no scroll at all), what am I missing?

```
  var s = skrollr.init({
    smoothScrolling: true,
    skrollrBody: document.getElementById('scrollable')
  });

  skrollr.menu.init(s, {
    animate: true,
    easing: 'sqrt'
  });
```

I also tried this as well as other variations of it that I found on [this post](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) and it always looks very jagged.

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $scrollable.animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

I also disabled all scroll events (and ultimately all JavaScript), then styles and HTML elements with fixed positioning, and scrolling's still rough.

Comment: I updated the post with some things i tried.